# ZendX Dialog inside ZendX Tab not beeing loaded correctly

Tags: zend-framework, dialog, tabcontainer, zendx

I'm having some trouble loading a dialog on the view that's going inside a TabContainer, all using ZendX. I'm having to load all the layout and JS of the app again so I can use these resources. Anyone knows what I need to load on my view, that I can load the dialogs passing it by ajax to my tabcontainer?
If I got to load the hole thing again, it gets too damn slow.

Here's a screenshoot of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdK0k.jpg

that's the effect i get loading all the layout and scripts again:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8qNr.jpg